# Ip parsing using regexp in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to parse IP address from a string:

```
>>> import re
>>> input_str = '''
kjhdkjfh shfkjdsh shfk 1.1.1.1 kaseroi 1.1.1.1 jsoiu 1.1.1.1 
1
1
11
123
132132.23213.213213.123213
23.23.23.23 2321321.33.3.3.3 3.3..3.3.3.3.3. 
3.3.3.3.3.3

3.3.3.3
34.5.6.7
agdi 123213.44.4.5 12.12.12.12
'''
>>> 
>>> 
>>> pattern = r"\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]?[0-9])\b"
>>> re.findall(pattern, input_str)
['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '23.23.23.23', '33.3.3.3', '3.3.3.3', '3.3.3.3', '3.3.3.3', '34.5.6.7', '12.12.12.12']
>>>
```

But the valid IP list is:

```
['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '23.23.23.23', '3.3.3.3', '34.5.6.7', '12.12.12.12']
```

Is there anything wrong with regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add negative lookahead and lookbehind in your pattern.

```
(?<!\.)\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]?[0-9])\b(?!\.\d?)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/52)

**OR**

```
(?<!\S)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]?[0-9])(?!\S)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/53)

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind asserts that (what or character) precedes the match would be any but not a non-space character.
- `(?!\S)`  Negative lookahead asserts that what follows the match would be any but not a non-space character.

Code:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!\S)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]?[0-9])(?!\S)', input_str)
['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '23.23.23.23', '3.3.3.3', '34.5.6.7', '12.12.12.12']
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `\b` to limit the regex because `.` is included within the `\b`. From the input string we can notice that the ips are delimited using space hence `\s` is a much better option.

Changing the regex with a lookarounds for `\s` would serve the pupose

```
>>> attern = r"(?<=\s)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]?[0-9])(?=\s)"
>>> re.findall(attern, input_str)
['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '23.23.23.23', '3.3.3.3', '34.5.6.7', '12.12.12.12']
```